# Registering tags taxonomy for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, tags

The actual post type support categories and I want to add also support for tags.

I have this code:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'category_' . $slug,
    array( $slug ), 
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => "$slug Categories",
        'singular_label' => "$slug Category",
        'rewrite' => true
    )
);
```

So, I was trying to duplicate this for supporting tags but is not working.

This is the entire code for portfolio post type :

```
$portfolio_slugs = get_option("zeitgeist_portfolio_slug");
if(is_array($portfolio_slugs))
    foreach ( $portfolio_slugs as $slug ){
        add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
        register_taxonomy("category_".$slug, array($slug), 
        array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "$slug Categories", "singular_label" => "$slug Category", "rewrite" => true));
        register_taxonomy("tags_".$slug, array($slug), array("hierarchical" => false, "label" => "$slug Tags", "singular_label" => "$slug Tags", "rewrite" => true));



function create_portfolio() {
    $portfolio_slugs = get_option("zeitgeist_portfolio_slug");
    $portfolio_counter = 0;
    $portfolio_names = get_option("zeitgeist_portfolio_name");
    foreach ( $portfolio_slugs as $slug ){
        $portfolio_args = array(
            'label' => __("Portfolio '".$portfolio_names[$portfolio_counter]."'"),
            'singular_label' => __($portfolio_names[$portfolio_counter++]),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug, 'with_front' => true),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'comments', 'excerpt')
        );
        register_post_type($slug,$portfolio_args);
    }
}

function portfolioSingleRedirect(){
    global $wp_query;
    $queryptype = $wp_query->query_vars["post_type"];
    $portfolio_slugs = get_option("zeitgeist_portfolio_slug");
    if(is_array($portfolio_slugs))
        foreach ( $portfolio_slugs as $slug ){
            if ($queryptype == $slug){
                if (have_posts()){
                    global $pcat;
                    $pcat = "category_".$slug;
                    require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_portfolio.php');
                    die();
                }else{
                    $wp_query->is_404 = true;
                }
            }
        }
}
add_action("template_redirect", 'portfolioSingleRedirect');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The categories your code creates is a custom taxonomy, not the default post `category` taxonomy.

Anyway, if you want to add support for the default post tags taxonomy, the name is `post_tag` and can be added via the `taxonomies` argument in your `$portfolio_args`:

```
$portfolio_args = array(
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
    // all of your other portfolio args
);
```

See [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) in Codex for more info.

Comment: Actually I need a custom taxonomy tag exactly like the categories taxonomy in my code

Comment: in `register_taxonomy` arguments change `'hierarchical' => true` to `'hierarchical' => false` to make them behave like the default tags taxonomy.

Comment: I've tried to register a new taxonomy like categories but with hierarchical - false but is still not working. Or if you can make an edit of my code maybe I miss something.

Comment: what's not working exactly? you've created a taxonomy and it's not hierarchical? if your problems are simply php errors, I suggest [enabling debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and working through them line by line.

Comment: I've duplicated the register_taxonomy it was used for creating the categories but with hierarchical - false  and I recieve : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 52 which is the last line in my code

Comment: I've updated also my code, the code for tags taxonomy is exactly after the register_taxonomy for the categories

Comment: your foreach is missing the closing brace. use a proper IDE or editor that can highlight and identify these sorts of errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )` like others have said, but you also have to add 'taxonomies' in the 'supports' argument for the taxonomy boxes to show up in the admin page, like so

```
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','taxonomies')
```